# Repeated rows in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I feel like I'm going insane because I can't figure out what feels like should be a simple problem! I want to generate fake data in a numpy array and I can't figure out how to repeat a row of observations. I'd rather generate thousands of rows and I can't figure out how to repeat a row whenever I feel like.

For example, here's my current code:

```
voters = np.array(
    [
        ['Democrat', 'Republican', 'Third'],
        ['Democrat', 'Republican', 'Third'],
        ['Democrat', 'Republican', 'Third'],
        ['Democrat', 'Republican', 'Third'],
        ['Democrat', 'Republican', 'Third'],
        ['Democrat', 'Third', 'Republican'],
        ['Democrat', 'Third', 'Republican'],
        ['Democrat', 'Third', 'Republican'],
        ['Democrat', 'Third', 'Republican'],
    ]
)
```

But I just want to be able to condense this. It's obviously not manageable to make large datasets this way!

Thank you

Comment: Please read the descriptions for tags before using them

Comment: Do you want to generate thousands of identical rows or should each row be randomly ordered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.repeat()`:

```
voters = np.array([['row1', 'row1', 'row1'],
                   ['row2', 'row2', 'row2']])

# We repeat 2 times the first row and 4 times the second row.
np.repeat(voters,[2,4],axis=0)
# voters.repeat([2,4],axis=0) produce the same result.
```

And we obtain:

```
array([['row1', 'row1', 'row1'],
       ['row1', 'row1', 'row1'],
       ['row2', 'row2', 'row2'],
       ['row2', 'row2', 'row2'],
       ['row2', 'row2', 'row2'],
       ['row2', 'row2', 'row2']])
```

Comment: Oh my gosh I had visited that page before but had a complete misunderstanding of how its syntax worked. This is it--thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
np.array([['Democrat', 'Republican', 'Third']]* 10000)
```

to generate as many duplicate rows as you want.

Comment: How do I do this for multiple lines? Because
'''
voters = np.array(
    [['Democrat', 'Republican', 'Thurd']] * 10,
    [['Democrat', 'Third', 'Republican']] * 4          
)
voters
'''
just gets me a type error

Comment: Please have a look at @obchardon's answer. it answers your comment